# ElasticSearch Nest BulkAll halted after receiving failures that can not be retried from _bulk

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Using `BulkAll()` to bulk insert I'm receiving this strange error

```
BulkAll halted after receiving failures that can not be retried from _bulk
```

However Im still getting a successful response when I examine the exception:

```
Successful low level call on POST: /cf-lblogs-2019.01.23/cloudflareloadbalancinglogelasticentity/_bulk?
```

What am I doing wrong here? Below is the code snippet:

```
var waitHandle = new CountdownEvent(1);

var bulk = _client.BulkAll(group.ToList(), a => a
                .Index(_index.Replace("*", string.Empty) + group.Key)
                .BackOffRetries(2)
                .BackOffTime("30s")
                .RefreshOnCompleted(true)
                .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(4)
                .Size(group.Count()));

bulk.Subscribe(new BulkAllObserver(
                onNext: response => _logger.LogInformation($"Indexed {response.Page * group.Count()} with {response.Retries} retries"),
                onError: HandleInsertError,
                onCompleted: () => waitHandle.Signal()
            ));

waitHandle.Wait();


private void HandleInsertError(Exception e)
    {
        var exceptionString = e.ToString(); 
        _logger.LogError(exceptionString);
    }
```

Nest 6.4.2.

Elastic 6.5.4.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I've solved it like below:

```
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        int seenPages = 0;
        int requests = 0;
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ConcurrentBag<BulkResponse> bulkResponses = new ConcurrentBag<BulkResponse>();
        ConcurrentBag<BulkAllResponse> bulkAllResponses = new ConcurrentBag<BulkAllResponse>();
        ConcurrentBag<items> deadLetterQueue = new ConcurrentBag<items>();
        BulkAllObservable<items> observableBulk = elasticClient.BulkAll(lst, f => f
                .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
                .BulkResponseCallback(r =>
                {
                    bulkResponses.Add(r);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref requests);
                })
                .ContinueAfterDroppedDocuments()
                .DroppedDocumentCallback((r, o) =>
                {
                    errors.Add(r.Error.Reason);
                    deadLetterQueue.Add(o);
                })
                .BackOffTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                .BackOffRetries(2)
                .Size(1000)
                .RefreshOnCompleted()
                .Index(indeksName)
                .BufferToBulk((r, buffer) => r.IndexMany(buffer))
            , tokenSource.Token);

        try
        {
            observableBulk.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), b =>
            {
                bulkAllResponses.Add(b);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref seenPages);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exxx => " + e.Message);
        }
        foreach (var err in errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : " + err);
        }
```

I hope it may help someone else who also has this issue.

Answer (score 5):

This means that the `BulkAll` observable is unable to index one or more documents that have failed for a reason that cannot be retried.

By default, the retry predicate for documents that cannot be indexed is when a HTTP response status code of 429 is returned for an item i.e. attempting to concurrently index more documents than the cluster is able to handle.

Two things jump out looking at the `BulkAll()` setup:

1. `var bulk = _client.BulkAll(group.ToList(), a => a`

   `group.ToList()` will immediately evaluate **all documents** and buffer them in a `List<T>` in memory. For efficiency, you usually want to *lazily* enumerate a large collection when bulk indexing. If `group` is an `IEnumerable<T>` that can be passed to `BulkAll`, then just pass that.
2. `.Size(group.Count()));`

   This is going to try to send **all documents** in one bulk request. The idea with `BulkAll` is that it will send multiple bulk requests concurrently, and keep doing so until all documents have been indexed.

   Size should be set to a reasonable size for each request; you might calculate a reasonable size in bytes by calculating the average number of bytes per document and then start with somewhere less than 5MB, or you may want to start with say 1000 documents per request and evaluate whether the speed of indexing is sufficient for your needs or if you start to get 429 responses returned. When the latter starts to happen, it's a good indication that you're near the threshold of the indexing limit for the cluster for the documents you're indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't doubt Russ Cams answer is correct, but there is another scenario where this error is possible.

If you have implemented API security in Elastic search using something like

```
POST /_security/api_key
{
"name":"my-api-key",
"role_descriptors": {
   "admin": {
       "cluster":["all"],
       "index": [
          {
            "names":["my-index", "my-other-index"],
            "privileges": ["all"]
          }
        ]
     }
   }
}
```

And you're not using the correct ApiKey for those indexes, OR are attempting to use the generated ApiKey to create and bulkAll into another index, which has no ApiKey defined for it.

Instead of receiving an error during the delete / create calls..

```
await client.Indices.DeleteAsync(IndexName);
await client.Indices.CreateAsync(IndexName, MutateCreateIndexDescriptor);
```

You'll get the error you specified in your question.

```
BulkAll halted after receiving failures that can not be retried from _bulk
```

With a stack trace pointing you incorrectly to:

```
bulkAll.Wait(... , ...);
```

if defined.

This might be a bug in NEST. experienced it in version. 7.8.0 Hope this helps anyone who stumbles across it.