# Bulk indexing failed and after retrying 2 times. at Nest.BulkAllObservable`1.<BulkAsync>d__20.MoveNext()

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

ElastiSearch 7.x is working completely fine with 7.15.x Nest Client and then I have migrated to ElasticSearch 8.8.1 and its response has shown that "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0".
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf6xB.png)

As suggested upgraded the Nest Client to 7.17.5 but it is throwing the following error,
Error: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Bulk indexing failed and after retrying 2 times.
at Nest.BulkAllObservable`1.<BulkAsync>d__20.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Nest.BulkAllObservable`1.d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Nest.BulkAllObservable`1.<BulkAsync>d__20.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Nest.BulkAllObservable`1.d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Nest.BulkAllObservable`1.<BulkAsync>d__20.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Nest.Extensions.<ProcessAsync>d__30`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Nest.Extensions.d__29`2.MoveNext()

I have found similar articles, which are related to bulk but none of the solutions worked, adding the links below:
[Nest BulkAll - Error: ‘BulkAll halted after receiving failures that can not be retried from _bulk’](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nest-bulkall-error-bulkall-halted-after-receiving-failures-that-can-not-be-retried-from-bulk/304949)
[ElasticSearch Nest BulkAll halted after receiving failures that can not be retried from _bulk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348798/elasticsearch-nest-bulkall-halted-after-receiving-failures-that-can-not-be-retri)

Also, gone through the Indexing documentation of 7.17 Nest Client and the code is exactly as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/indexing-documents.html)

Found a bug logged for ["BulkAll should classify retried and failed documents as dropped"](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/6647) The branch name is bulkall-fixes and the description of the [Pull Request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/6801) says "Will manually port this to 7.17 once this is merged." Not sure if it's backported to 7.17.x as the labels talk only about 8.x
[Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJIvt.png)

The error is same if we use Nest Client 7.15.0 to connect to Elastic Search 8.8.1.

I wanted to upgrade the Nest Client to 8.x but the internal architecture got changed and I have to make changes to my code. Can anyone tell me - how to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you check elasticsearch logs error?

Comment: Yeah, I did, and no error in the ES logs. Do you want me to look at any specific logs @LeBigCat  ?

Comment: Just ansking, a good thing you check it wasnot server side issue ;)